# Error when xml is parsed in windows phone 7

Tags: c#, linq, windows-phone-7, xml-parsing

The below xml to be parsed in my windows phone application.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist>
   <dict>
  <key>2013</key>
   <dict>
      <key>January</key>
        <dict>
        <key>Girivalam</key>
        <dict>
            <key>StartDate</key>
            <date>2013-01-26T04:10:00Z</date>
            <key>EndDate</key>
            <date>2013-01-27T05:26:00Z</date>
            <key>FullMoon</key>
            <date>2013-01-26T04:10:00Z</date>
        </dict>
                </dict>
       </dict>
      </dict>
</plist>
```

I parsed it using following code.

```
   private void Parsing()
    {
        using (XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(new StringReader("/Parse/appmodel-data.xml")))
        {
            XDocument document = XDocument.Load(reader);
            IEnumerable<XElement> AuthElement = from elements in document.Descendants("dict")
                                                select elements;
        }
    }
```

When i execute the application iam getting the error **"Data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position 1."** Can anyone correct me where i went wrong?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Put a break point  and see if document is getting loaded into document variable

Comment: ya i done...On that line only iam getting this runtime exception...

Comment: Is the XML file an application resource?

Comment: yes...Its an app resource

Comment: Others have explained how to do this, but you should understand what went wrong too: look at what `StringReader` does. Currently you're not loading the file at all... you're trying to parse the *string* "/Parse/appmodel-data.xml" as if it were XML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mark the file as a resource and try the following;

```
System.IO.Stream fileStream = Application.GetResourceStream(new Uri(@"/Change this with the AssemblyName;component/Parse/appmodel-data.xml",UriKind.Relative)).Stream;

XDocument document = XDocument.Load(fileStream);                        
IEnumerable<XElement> AuthElement = from elements in document.Descendants("dict")
                                        select elements;
```

Comment: ya i done. I marked file as resource.. but still getting null reference

Comment: private void Parsing()
        {
            System.IO.Stream fileStream = Application.GetResourceStream(new Uri(@"/Data%20Parsing;component/Parse/appmodel-data.xml", UriKind.Relative)).Stream;
            XDocument document = XDocument.Load(fileStream);
            IEnumerable<XElement> AuthElement = from elements in document.Descendants("dict")
                                                select elements;
        }

Comment: Is your assembly name "Data Parsing"?

Comment: i got solution.. this has worked for me..  var resource = Application.GetResourceStream(new Uri(@"/Data%20Parsing;component/Parse/appmodel-data.xml", UriKind.Relative));

            StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(resource.Stream);
            string x = streamReader.ReadToEnd();

Answer (score 1):

```
StreamResourceInfo xml = Application.GetResourceStream(new Uri("/ProjectName;component/FileFolder/filename.xml", UriKind.Relative));
XElement xmlElement = XElement.Load(xml.Stream);
```

You can use your statements itself. Only thing is referring the path of the XML correctly.